# Blazor Child RenderTemplate Identifier Expected

Tags: c#, blazor

I am learning blazor and I am creating a SCRUM backlog application. I am traditionally a desktop developer, so I might be trying to do something every wacky. I am currently building out an accordion control. I have this working very well. However, when I try to bind the child Render Template to another accordion I get Identifier Expected exception. Can anyone help explain this?

Collapsible.razor

```
<div>
    <button class="ms-Icon @_buttonText" @onclick="OpenClose"></button>
    @ItemTemplate
    <div class="@_collapse">
        @if (Children != null)
        {
            @foreach (T child in Children)
            {
                @ChildTemlpate(child);
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Backlog.razor

```
@foreach (Epic epic in _epics)
{
    <Collapsible IsOpen="false" Children="@epic.Features">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span>
                @epic.Name
            </span>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ChildTemlpate>
            <Collapsible Children="@context.Items" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <span>
                        Feature 
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ChildTemlpate Context="context.Items">
                    <span>items</span>                    
                </ChildTemlpate>
            </Collapsible>
        </ChildTemlpate>
    </Collapsible>
}
```

Comment: Is `<ChildTemlpate Context="context.Items">` missing the `@` before context?

Comment: no, if you add the @ you get s different exception

Comment: That's not supposed to happen? Which line is throwing the Identifier expected error?

Comment: When you set the Context parameter of a render fragment, you are setting an alias for the name, so where you have Context='context.items' it is wrong, you just want to alias context as items so just use Context='items'

Comment: @MisterMagoo That was it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the Context parameter of a render fragment, you are setting an alias for the name.

So where you have Context='context.items' it is wrong, you just want to alias context as items so just use Context='items'